# integrate PayUMoney in ofbiz

Tags: ofbiz, payumoney

how to configure PayUMoney as a payment gateway in apache ofbiz 14.12 or ofbiz 13.07.01 ?

I have followed below links, but it doesnt help much.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Third+Party+Payment+and+Shipment+Configuration

and

[Configure Authorize.net in Apache OFBiz as a Payment Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554825/configure-authorize-net-in-apache-ofbiz-as-a-payment-gateway)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

For a better experience ask such questions in the user ml of the Apache OFBiz project, see [here](https://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html).

Best regards,

Pierre